# comparing strings comeing from different widgets

Tags: string

When I compare between tow values one coming from an EditText and the other from a TextView I always get that they don't match even if they are the same word

Why would that happen?

Comment: You need to show us your code. We can't help you without the code ... also, you need to add the language and framework that you use in the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `==` ? you could try and use `.equals()` instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot

But why is it like that

I mean they are both strings so the == method should work

Comment: Take a look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java Glad i could help! ps: the next time you should provide more code and tell us what language your using :)

Comment: Ok,sorry about that

Comment: no problem ! :) could you mark the question as answered ?